# Cryptic clue : Rub....[6]

Tags: cryptic-clues

This is a single cryptic clue.

> Rub rex, it will hide political change [6]

(clue improved after helpful comments from Rubio.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> Brexit, which is the word coined for the UK's exit from the European Union.

Explanation:

> This is a hidden word clue:
>  *Ru **b rex, it** will give political change.*

Comment: Yes, good job, well done

Comment: @tom I like it :). This type of clue should have an **indicator** though.

Comment: @Rubio - great - (right letter count this time).. what sort of indicator? - a question mark - or a word to show that something is hidden?

Comment: @tom [This link](http://www.crosswordunclued.com/2008/08/digging-out-hidden-words.html) should help (spoilers alert)

Comment: @Rubio - should the clue have been - 'Rub rex, it will hide political change?'    ?

Comment: @tom I think that would work, yes :)

Comment: @Rubio - many thanks for the link :-) - bookmarked, so now I will have no excuse for the mistakes....